# How do I get Joomla to stop opening every link in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, hyperlink

I changed a domain name of my website, and now every link opens in new tab (menu, logo, external links etc.) I want to know how to get back to normal behavior when Joomla opens only external links in new window. How can I solve this and what could be the cause of it?

Link to my website: http://sparkle-soft.com

I'm using Joomla 2.5

Comment: Please edit your question, this has absolutely nothing to do with Joomla. Your browser opens pages in a new tab because a script on your site, which isn't part of Joomla, is instructing it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a inline script tag in your head for some sort of specialtrack. There is a line of code within the function that is applying a blank target attribute to all links on your page:

```
links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```

Check to see what tracking you have added to your site, look for any options if provided that would allow you to change this. It could be coming from an extension or your template but hard to tell as it's inline, rather than a source file.

Comment: Thanks, I`m trying to finds where to change this code on my website, but it is a little strange, error started to appear when I changed domain name... can my hosting provider "stick" this script to my website somehow?

Comment: @user3166813 - If your host is doing this then that is extremely bad. If you're using free hosting then this is most likely expected, however if you're paying for your hosting, then this should not be done. There could be however an option on your hosting control panel to turn off this special tracking, I'm not sure as I've never seen it before